# How to use eclox, the doxygen plugin for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, doxygen

How do I get eclox working in Eclipse 3.5?

I'm using Ubuntu 9.04. I installed Doxygen from ubuntu repositories(version 1.5.8). Then I installed eclox on eclipse through the update site.

Despite this, I don't get any option to in any menu to initiate it.

Also the [eclox site](http://home.gna.org/eclox/) doesn't seem to have any "getting started" guide.

Please help.

Comment: I found this instruction file really helpful :) [https://github.com/theolind/mahm3lib/wiki/Integrating-Doxygen-with-Eclipse](https://github.com/theolind/mahm3lib/wiki/Integrating-Doxygen-with-Eclipse)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Never mind, worked it out my self.

First you need to create a DoxyFile (which is the configuration file) by giving the source path and the output path.

Then only you can generate the documentation by right clicking the project and selecting the "Generate Documentation".

Thanks anyway!

Comment: Is this inside the project you want to document or where do i create the DoxyFile?

Comment: **To create a DoxyFile:** Right click the project > new > other > other > Doxyfile > Choose whatever path. **IMPORTANT:** Window > Preferences > C/C++ > Editor > Workspace default: **Doxygen** , **and**  Window > Preferences > Doxygen > **CHOOSE A VERSION - NOT UNKNOWN!!** - e.g. 1.8.13

Answer (score 29):

BTW there is a manual inside org.gna.eclox_0.8.0.jar, wierd they did not post this on the project site!!!

Here is the content

```
      Eclox, a Doxygen frontend plugin for Eclipse.
            <http://gna.org/projects/eclox>
```

1. INSTALLATION

   There are two options to install the plugin: using the update site or
   using the packaged feature.

   The update site is the more convenient way to install eclox. It is
   located at https://anb0s.github.io/eclox. See eclipse's user
   guilde for additionnal details.

   When using the packaged feature, you must extract the archive content into
   your eclipse's root location. For additionnal details, please refer to
   eclipse's user guide.
2. CONFIGURATION

   Once the plugin installed, you must ensure that the default PATH environment
   variable makes the doxygen binary reachable for the plugin. If not, you can
   update PATH to include to directory containing the Doxygen binary, or you can
   tell Eclox where that binary is located on your system (which is in my opinion
   the better solution). To do this, open eclipse's preference edition dialog
   window and go into the new "Doxygen" section.
3. USAGE

   You can create new Doxygen projects (also called doxyfiles) using the 
   creation wizard. Go to "File->New->Other->Other->Doxygen Configuration". Press
   next and set both file location and name. Then a empty doxyfile will be
   created at the specified location, the wizard automatically adds the
   ".Doxyfile" extension.

   You should now see a file with a blue @-sign icon. This is your new
   doxyfile. Double-clicking on it will open the editor. You can now browse and
   edit the settings.

   Once your have properly set all doxyfile fields, you can launch a
   documentation build using the toolbar icon showing a blue @-sign. In 
   the case the button is not visible in the toolbar, your current perspective
   needs to get configured. Go to "Window->Customize perspective->Commands" and
   in "Available command groups" check "Doxygen". Additionnaly, you can browse
   the laetest builds by clicking the down arrow right to the toolbar button.

   When the documentation build starts, a new view showing the build log opens.
   In its toolbar, a button named "Stop" allows you to halt the current build
   process. The current build also appears in the Eclipse job progress view and
   you can control the job from there.

   The build toolbar action determine the next doxyfile to build depending on
   the current active workbench part (editor or view) and the current selection
   in that part. For example, if the active part is a doxyfile editor, the next
   doxyfile to build will be the one being edited. If the active part is the
   resource explorer and the current selection is a doxyfile, that doxyfile will
   be next to get build. In the case the active part selection doesn't correspond
   to a doxyfile, the last built doxyfile will be rebuiled. And if the build
   history is empty, you will be asked for the doxyfile to build.

HTH Anybody

Answer (score 3):

I just faced a problem setting the **Doxygen binary path** in eclox 0.8.0 settings in Eclipse on **Mac OS X** 10.7.
There is no way to configure the path via *Eclipse-preferences*->*Doxygen*.

**The solution is to edit the preferences file manually**

1. add a (fake) location, let's say `/Applications`, using the wizard mentioned above.
2. close Eclipse
3. edit this file:
   `$WORKSPACE/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/org.gna.eclox.core.prefs`:
   Replace the value for `doxygen.default` (currently `eclox.core.doxygen.CustomDoxygen /Applications\n`) with `eclox.core.doxygen.CustomDoxygen /Applications/Doxygen.app/Contents/Resources/doxygen\n`.
4. restart Eclipse

Answer (score 1):

For MacOS user there is a very easy way to get around via the issue of the Doxygen version selection. The link that provides details is here:https://github.com/theolind/mahm3lib/wiki/Integrating-Doxygen-with-Eclipse

After installing the Eclox plugging:

1)"go to "Eclipse --> Preferences --> Oxygen"
2)"Press Shift+CMD+G then Add: "/Applications/Doxygen.app/Contents/Resources/doxygen"
3) Doxygen's version should be displayed

Answer (score 0):

this might help you or any windows user trying to install eclox:

Tutorial for Installing eclox — Document Transcript

Step 1: go to eclox website (http://home.gna.org/eclox/) and to copy the update link address.Step

step 2: Insert the link into the update manager in eclipse and press OK.

Step 3: Select the Eclox item and to complete the installation.

Step 4: When the installation has done, you should select a project that you want to generate thedoxygen documents. Then, create a doxygen project for it.

Step 5: config the options. Note: You have to provide the “Input directories” correctly and to select the “Scan recursively”item. Finally, save the configuration file.

Step 6: find out the “@” and to choice “Choose Doxyfile...”.

Step 7: select a doxyfile.Step 8: wait for few seconds and the doucments will be generated.

its from this link:   http://www.slideshare.net/pickerweng/tutorial-for-installing-eclox

Comment: Do you think you could look at formatting this better? Its a wall of text and lacks screen shots from the original slideshare.

Answer (score 0):

Like claus I had to dig into the preferences file maually, because eclox 0.8.0 would just not take a good path from Eclipse Preferences file chooser.
So, edit this file: `$WORKSPACE/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/org.gna.eclox.core.prefs` and alter the given path (in my case I had to change from

```
doxygen.default=eclox.core.doxygen.CustomDoxygen C\:\\Programm Files\\doxygen\\bin
```

to this

```
doxygen.default=eclox.core.doxygen.CustomDoxygen C\:\\Programme\\doxygen\\bin
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I find a webpage https://github.com/theolind/mahm3lib/wiki/Integrating-Doxygen-with-Eclipse where you can find more details. Especially, for Mac users, you need to **Press Shift+CMD+G then Add: "/Applications/Doxygen.app/Contents/Resources/doxygen"** when you configure the doxygen in eclipse before compiling .doxygfile by using Eclox.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative from eclipse is to use **Javadoc**:

1. From menu (...Search Project Run...)

Project > Generate Javadoc

2. You should be in Java project and add comments with tags.

!!!

Comment: This does not indicate how to use Eclox - or indeed Doxygen markup, since Javadoc markup is specific to Java; Doxygen is multi-lingual (eg works under Eclipse CDT)